# MySQL indexing - optional search criteria

Tags: mysql, indexing

"How many indexes should I use?" This question has been asked *generally* multiple times, I know. But I'm asking for an answer specific to my table structure and querying purposes.

I have a table with about 60 columns. I'm writing an SDK which has a function to fetch data based on optional search criteria. There are 10 columns for which the user can **optionally** pass in values (so the user might want all entries for a certain `username` and `clientTimestamp`, or all entries for a certain `userID`, etc). So potentially, we could be looking up data based on up to 10 columns.

This table will run `INSERTS` almost as often as `SELECTS`, and the table will usually have somewhere around 200-300K rows. Each row contains a significant amount of data (probably close to 0.5 MB).

Would it be a good or bad idea to have 10 indexes on this table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple guide that may help you make a decision. 
1. Index columns that have high selectivity.
2. Try normalizing your table (you mentioned username and userid columns; if it's not user table, no need for storing name here)
3. If your system is not abstract, it should be a number of parameters that are used more often than others. First of all, make sure you have indexes that support fast result retrieval with such parameters.

Comment: Pretty much what I was thinking as well...to make an educated guess as to what will be used most often. As for normalizing the table, I know what you mean and agree, but this is a different scenario. When `username` is populated it is for an "offline user" (which means no record exists in the `users` table) while when `userID` is populated it is for an "online user" (which refers to a user in the `users` table).